# The attribute 'autoeventwireup' is not allowed in this page error on my SharePoint admin center

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-admin-center

I have recently migrated the SharePoint Online from our older domain to the new domain. During the migration one of the site got merged with the Site Collection and messed up the entire site collection.

Then I tried to reset the site collection definition, and it gave me an error **Access Denied**, though I am the SharePoint Admin.

The second option I tried is to delete the existing site collection and re-create it from scratch. To do this, I logged into the SharePoint admin center, and then it gave me the error **The attribute 'autoeventwireup' is not allowed in this page **.

Basically, I am just unable to open the SharePoint admin center and see all the site collections. As soon as click on it, it throws this error.

I am struggling hard to rectify this, but really not reaching to any solution. If I type in the URL of the site in the browser, then I can access the site. But If I want to do this through admin center its just throwing the same error.

I tried with multiple browsers as well, but of no help.

Is there a way I can access my site collections from within the SharePoint admin center because I want to create the new site collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have described it, you will need to raise a support ticket with Microsoft from the Office 365 Admin portal.

They will be able to fix the issues for SharePoint Admin.

You should be able to see the tenant and site properties using [SharePoint Online Client Browser](https://github.com/bramdejager/spcb) However you should still raise the ticket with Microsoft.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have already raised the ticket with the Microsoft and they are looking into it. However, as it has been more than a week, I was just trying it myself, if I can do something.

Comment: If you think the answer is still useful for yourself or others please upvote.

Comment: Thanks for marking answer. Hope it is being dealt with promptly by Microsoft. If you receive any insight into the issue that may help others please let us know